# How to get the alphanumerical token of a JLabel in a JLabel[] to pass to the method

Tags: java, arrays, swing, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an element from `jlb[]` to the method `new1(JLabel jl)`. Here is my code:

```
    JLabel jlb[]=new JLabel[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        jlb[i]=new JLabel("jlbl"+i);
    }
    new1(<variable name>);
```

`new1` is a method. It has a `JLabel` parameter. I want call `new1()`. What should I place instead of `<variable name>` to call the method with variable from the array?

This is `new1` method:

```
void new1(final JLabel jlbl){
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int y=10;
            while (b>=150) {                    
                for (int b=300; b > 150; b--) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        jlbl.setLocation(b, y);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            jLabel1.setLocation(b, y);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Yours appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) type question. No variable *name* exists for the JLabel that you're looking for, since it is held by an array. Instead its reference is via the array and an index: `jlb[3]` for instance. The question is -- how do you choose which JLabel in the array is the one you want, and this is something you never tell us.

Comment: You would call `new1(jlb[someindex])`. Hint: read about good naming. Your method and variable names are simply saying nothing. The idea of a good name is that it tells the reader something about the intention of the thing behind it. Your names simply dont communicate anything.

Comment: Another problem is that you are calling key Swing methods within a background thread, and are using a while true loop rather than a more appropriate Swing Timer, but that's unrelated to your main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are looking for a alphanumerical `token` that would identify your variable like `myJLabel` or `cuteLabelFromAnArray`. Well, data stored in arrays can be accessed with special operator `[]`. In your example this would be for example:

```
new1(jlb[<put index here>]);
```